# pass onChange from parent to child component failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not able to type out an input making a class base component, what's the problem?

```js
const { useState } = React;

class CustomComponentInClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { handleOnChange, value } = this.props;

    return <input type="text" onChange={handleOnChange} value={value} />;
  }
}

/*export default*/ function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleOnChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" onChange={handleOnChange} value={value} />
      <CustomComponentInClass onChange={handleOnChange} value={value} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I expect both field will behave the same, but CustomComponentInClass isn't 'typeable'

Comment: You're passing the handleOnChange function as onChange to your CustomComponentInClass component. To access it in the CustomComponentInClass you need to access it through this.props.onChange.

Comment: ^^ so basically, a typo-level mistake. Voted to close as such. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `CustomComponentInClass`, your  `handleOnChange` is undefined since you are passing the prop as onChange. If you use

```
<CustomComponentInClass handleOnChange={handleOnChange} value={value} />
```

instead

```
<CustomComponentInClass onChange={handleOnChange} value={value} />
```

, it will work